# specified foreach inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum

i have some hmm ... i think some illogical logic which is i think by myself ...
for now i can show you this :

```
$new ['period_10th'] = $periodic_items [9] ;
            foreach ($new ['period_10th'] as $item) { $po_10th [] = $item -> po_id ; }
          $new ['uni_10'] = array_unique($po_10th) ;
          foreach ($new ['uni_10'] as $po_id) {
            $po = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_po_by_id (md5($po_id)) ;
            $pos_10 [] = $po ['po_id'] ;
            $currency10 [] = $po ['currency'] ;
          }
          $cur_pos_10 = array_unique($currency10) ;
          foreach ($cur_pos_10 as $currency) {
            $new ['po_arr_10'] = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_pos_with_curr ($pos_10,$currency) ;
              foreach ($new ['po_arr_10'] as $key) {
                $test [] = $key -> total_line_price;
              }
              print_r($test);echo "<br><br>";
              print_r(array_sum($test));echo "<br><br>";
          }
```

that's will value

```
Array ( [0] => 20700000.00 [1] => 10340000.00 [2] => 4160000.00 [3] => 8150000.00 [4] => 9065000.00 [5] => 3500000.00 [6] => 2530000.00 [7] => 650000.00 [8] => 4395000.00 [9] => 17100000.00 [10] => 11250000.00 [11] => 6900000.00 [12] => 300000.00 [13] => 15750000.00 )

114790000

Array ( [0] => 20700000.00 [1] => 10340000.00 [2] => 4160000.00 [3] => 8150000.00 [4] => 9065000.00 [5] => 3500000.00 [6] => 2530000.00 [7] => 650000.00 [8] => 4395000.00 [9] => 17100000.00 [10] => 11250000.00 [11] => 6900000.00 [12] => 300000.00 [13] => 15750000.00 [14] => 1200000.00 )

115990000
```

I need to calculate the first array till end array (as many $cur_pos_10), but it always recalculate the entire array for the second value to the end. Please help me, and im really sorry for my bad english.

I need this :
first result calculate array [0] to [13];
second result calculate array [14] only;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well indented and aligned code is important. I have indented and aligned your code. As @Kazz indicated the problem is that you are not resetting the $test variable. Some comments in the code will also be valuable.

```
<?php

$new['period_10th'] = $periodic_items[9] ;
foreach ($new['period_10th'] as $item) {
    $po_10th[] = $item->po_id ;
}

$new['uni_10'] = array_unique($po_10th) ;
foreach ($new['uni_10'] as $po_id) {
    $po           = $this->model_prcsys->get_po_by_id (md5($po_id)) ;
    $pos_10[]     = $po ['po_id'] ;
    $currency10[] = $po ['currency'] ;
}

$cur_pos_10 = array_unique($currency10) ;
foreach ($cur_pos_10 as $currency) {
    $new['po_arr_10'] = $this->model_prcsys->get_pos_with_curr ($pos_10,$currency) ;

    $test = array(); // this was missing and probably causing problems
    foreach ($new['po_arr_10'] as $key) {
        $test[] = $key->total_line_price;
    }

    print_r($test);
    echo "<br><br>";
    print_r(array_sum($test));
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand, unclear what code should do, but it looks like you just need to define variables for storing results before `foreach` because `$test []` will push value to an array `$test` and variable `$test` is defined inside `foreach` and accumulate all the results over multiple loops. So try this:

```
$new ['period_10th'] = $periodic_items [9] ;
foreach ($new ['period_10th'] as $item) { $po_10th [] = $item -> po_id ; }
$new ['uni_10'] = array_unique($po_10th) ;

$pos_10 = []; // added
$currency10 = []; // added
foreach ($new ['uni_10'] as $po_id) {
  $po = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_po_by_id (md5($po_id)) ;
  $pos_10 [] = $po ['po_id'] ; // possibly similar problem if whole code is in loop or is executed multiple times
  $currency10 [] = $po ['currency'] ; // possibly similar problem if whole code is in loop or is executed multiple times
}

$cur_pos_10 = array_unique($currency10) ;
foreach ($cur_pos_10 as $currency) {
  /* in your code
      in first iteration variable $test is undefined
      in second iteration variable $test is defined and count($test) == 14
  */
  $new ['po_arr_10'] = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_pos_with_curr ($pos_10,$currency) ;
  $test = []; // added, variable $test is set to an empty array and erase previous results
  foreach ($new ['po_arr_10'] as $key) {
    $test [] = $key -> total_line_price;  // problem was here
  }
  print_r($test);echo "<br><br>";
  print_r(array_sum($test));echo "<br><br>";
}
```